# File Manager, unable to edit file

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager, files

I'm using EE 2.8.1, I can't edit a file in file manager.  If I go to: Content > Files > File Manager.  Select and file and under the Actions column, select edit, I get a page saying I'm not authorised to perform. This happens when I'm logged in as a super admin, and when the client logs in with under their member group as well.

Answer (score 0):

are your file upload preferences properly setup, folder permissions writtable?